# How to hide the API Post URL in Windows Desktop Application?

Tags: .net

I am developing a Windows Desktop application for which I want to register Machine ID and Install date as soon as they install or when starting the app for the first time.
I know the concepts of API and how to call this from Win APP, However, I see a problem here, What if a user reverse engineers the Application, gets the POST URL of my API and starts calling it from Postman to register other Machine IDs?
How can I avoid this?
Suppose if I am going to use secret and key for the APIs, where can I save it on the user machine?

Comment: The problem here is you need state - Couldn't you just keep a count of registrations per machine id in a database and not allow a registration if it's already been registered - or until it is unregistered?

Comment: But, how do I keep a count, I will know the new registrations only when they install the application, say if I am going to generate a GUID for each machine

Comment: Well you have to maintain a license system with a user id like an email and a product key unique per user. Then you keep something like an argon2id version of the assigned key and let people register / deregister.